# Docker registry uses different certificate

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I've setup a docker registry with self signed certificates. I used openssl to generate these.

```
openssl req \
   -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -sha256 -keyout docker-reg_pri.key \
   -x509 -days 9132 -out docker-reg_pri.crt
```

And then I've deployed my docker registry.

```
sudo docker run -d \
   --restart=always \
   --name registry \
   -v "/docker/data:/var/lib/registry" \
   -v "/docker/certificates:/certs" \
   -e REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=0.0.0.0:443 \
   -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/docker-reg_pub.crt \
   -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/docker-reg_pri.key \
   -p 443:443 registry:2
```

I've verified the logs and saw the container was running without any errors.
But when I check the certificate in my browser by going to https://server/v2/, I see the certificate has a different fingerprint that the ones I've used to deploy the registry. All the metadata seems to be the same.

Why did this happen? How can I make my docker registry use self signed certificates?

The docker registry is running on a Linux machine and I'm using a Windows machine. To actually verify that these certificates are different I've downloaded the docker-reg_pub.crt from the server and I've exported the certificate from https://server/v2/ in Chrome. Then I've compared both certificates using the certificate viewer in Windows.

Comment: Eliminate the network, browser, and other variables from this. Verify the certificate from the host where the registry is running, using openssl s_client.

Comment: I've created a docker registry on my local pc as well. Turns out I have the same issue on my local machine as well, so it isn't an issue with the network. But it turns out this certificate is exactly the same as the one generated on the linux server. So at least it is consistent in generating another certificate.

Comment: Please include both of the openssl commands used to inspect the certificates, both in the certificate you loaded into the registry, and in the certificate seen on port 443, and include the full output of each of those commands. See [mcve] for more details.